# Calling java servlet from c#

Tags: c#, java, servlets

Is this possible, and if so can someone point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explain what do you mean by *calling* but you could definetely use a [web client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) to send an HTTP request to a remote url and fetch the result:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    string result = client.DownloadString("http://example.com/yoursevletaddress");
    // TODO: do something with the returned content from the servlet
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can  use HttpWebRequest as shown below,

> HttpWebRequest request =
> (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://sanserver:8080/IoSystem/ToAdd?CheckLetter=SAN");
>
> // Execute the request
>
> HttpWebResponse response =
> (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Answer (score 2):

Given the definition of a [Java Servlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet):

> A Servlet is a Java class in Java EE
>   that conforms to the Java Servlet API,
>   a protocol by which a Java class may
>   respond to HTTP requests. They are not
>   tied to a specific client-server
>   protocol, but are most often used with
>   this protocol. The word "Servlet" is
>   often used in the meaning of "HTTP
>   Servlet".

The correct way would be to "call" the servlet using an http request. In .net you can use the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

A couple years ago I did exactly that.  You can just do a http post to the URL where the servlet is and even pass query params.  In my case it was something like

http://myservlet.com?dbItem1=ipAddress&dbItem2=trackingInfo

Then the servlet can act as a DB backend or whatever.  I had the servlet spit out XML which is pretty much ready to read in C#.  The response can be made with `HttpWebRequest` and read with `HttpWebResponse`.